# style.css sheet on local host not saving correctly

Tags: css, wordpress

I am building a wordpress theme on a localhost, using phpmyadmin and Ampps.

I have pasted the following into the style.css folder

```
    body {

    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:  #333333
    background: #f4f4f4;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

header {

    background: #393939;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px 10px;

}

header h1 {

    color: #ffffff;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}

a {

    color: #333333;

}

article.post {

    border-bottom: 1px #cccccc solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}

.container {

    width:1020px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: auto;

}

.main {

        margin: 15px 0;

}

footer {

    background: #393939;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;

}

article.post a.button {

    display: inline-block;
    background:#333333;
    color:white;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin-bottom:  10px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.meta {

    background:#333333;
    color:white;
    padding: 5px;

}

.post-thumbnail img{

    width: 100%;
    height:auto;





.main-nav li{

    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;

}

.main-nav {

    background: #4169E1;
    color: #ffffff;

}
```

The code in my header.php folder is this:

```
<nav class="main-nav">

        <div class="container">

            <?php 
                $args = array(

                'theme_location'    => 'primary'

            );

            ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

And then the functions.php code is this:

```
function simple_theme_setup() {

        //Featured Image Support
        add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

        //Menus
        register_nav_menus(array(

            'primary'   => __('Primary Menu')

        ));
    }
```

I'm expecting to see the changes immediately on the site, as it has before, but this isn't occurring.

I go to "view page source" and click on the style.css link. it takes me there but the changes to the style sheet are not present.

I retried a couple of minutes later, and the changes to the stylesheet are present, but the changes have not taken effect on  the site.

I read that I may need to clear cache files so I cleared my browsing cache but that didn't do anything . Would anyone have any input on this?

EDIT: after some more digging, I'm getting the feeling it's some other style that's  overriding it that was declared earlier ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235731/css-changes-are-not-getting-reflected-why)). I put the `!important` tags on the main-nav styles but that still didn't return anything.

Comment: So did you clear your cache?

Comment: No i don't  know how to do that, I will put that in the question as well, thanks.

Comment: https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic

Comment: Got it, yeah I cleared  the web browsing cache and that still didn't do it.

Comment: If you're using Google Chrome, open Developer Tools (F12), click the _Network_ tab, then check _Disable cache_. As long as the Developer Tools window is open your browser will fetch a fresh set of resources (JS, CSS, images etc.)

Comment: Thanks, just tried that and it didn't do anything. I'm wondering if it's something in the functions.php or header.php folder

Comment: Did you save the file?

Comment: Yeah, on view page source it is showing all of my code completely updated

Comment: How about the CSS file?

Comment: Yeah that's saved and fine, I'm going to post the CSS code to the question, I think some other style may be over riding it but I'm not sure which

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, after the

```
.post-thumbnail img{

    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
```

I forgot the last `}`

Thanks to all who helped look though! just a testament to how one little thing can completely mess up the whole process.