# Make img in the table responsive in the mobilephone with css

Tags: html, css

I have website and i cannot make it responsive only header and footer are responsive I want to make img in tr make responsive without bootstrap. I  have tried everyting,please help I am newbie in frontend

```
tr.j {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/fN4yIQL.png') no-repeat;  position: relative; background-color: #fff; 


    width: 100%;
      border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;

    }



<tr class="j" >
            <td colspan="2"  valign="top" style="background: url('') no-repeat 50% 15%; background-size: 100px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px;width: 100%">

                <div class= "apps" >
                            <a href="http://icome.su/apps/ios"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/67E0pWQ.png" alt=""
style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>

                            <a href="http://icome.su/apps/android"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/nBRwQKL.png" alt=""></a>
                        </div>


                <a href="http://icome.su" ><h4 id ="my2">Скачайте презентацию ваших  бизнес-возможностей</h4></a>
                <a href="http://icome.su"><h4 id ="my3">Зарегистрируйтесь на сайте iCome</h4></a>

            </td>



      </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Just a little note: Try not to use tables for your layout, there are much better ways to create layouts with `div`'s etc.

Comment: First off all, stop using tables for creating layout. Second, create a jsfiddle with your code, it's easier to debug.

Comment: @Sharath Daniel https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=vl6Tn7PuVC

Comment: @Ruddy i have no time to make it with divs I should make it with tables

Comment: @Sultan You will run into problems with tables, I would even go as far to say it is easier to create a website with `div`'s. Tables are designed for tabular data not layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is naive: **you are specifying the `@media` rules before the standard rule**.

Since they have the same [CSS Specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21728972/1654265), the latter wins.

Just copy your `@media` rules at the end of your CSS file (or `<style>` block), and they will work.

#### [Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kyr6k2a7/)

<sub>Note that you have an error in one of your images.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can try in responsive css:

```
.apps a img{
         width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: `width: 100%` would make the image exceed it's natural size and would loose it's clarity.

Answer (score 1):

To Make an inline image responsive just add this to your css...

```
img {max-width: 100%;}
```